# how to check if once go to if block never go to else block

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

I'm developing webservice. 
In Request categories id are like,

```
$categories_string = 1,2,3,4,5.
```

In response i have to return json array with whole data (from 3-4 tables) associated with all ids. 
so i use explode() function for string to array. so after this code my array is,

```
$category_id_array = explode(',',$categories_string );
```

So , i got array in $category_id_array.

So Problem is that if there is a data in single categories i have to give response even if there is no data in other categories.

**Current Output :** 
From this code if there is data in 3 categories among 4 categories it will give (data of 3 and for 4th one there is no data so it will go to else block)
So is there a way to check if once go to if block never go to else block or any other logic for this functionality.

**Expected Output :** 
Functionality is that among 4 categories if there is data in one categories and not in other categories it show only first categories data if data is in 2 categories it will give data of 2 categories vice versa.

**Note :** I have to use else block here (if there is no data in all categories than it must respond with else block)

**So for that i use below code.**

```
          foreach ($category_id_array as $single_cat_value) {
                        $res_whole_criteria = $this->db->query("SELECT * , ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  '$latitude' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( longitude ) - RADIANS(  '$longitude' ) ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '$latitude' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, information_business.name AS business_name FROM information_business LEFT JOIN category ON information_business.category_id = category.id LEFT JOIN offers ON offers.category_id = category.id WHERE category.id =  '$single_cat_value' HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance");

                        $row_whole_criteria = $res_whole_criteria->result();
                        echo "<pre>";
                        print_r($row_whole_criteria);
                        $resultsDoExist = 'false';   // code edited 
                        $business_id = $row_whole_criteria['0']->business_id;

                        // code for count business_wise_like starts here 

                        $like_count_businesswise = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT( id ) AS business_wise_like FROM  `business_likes` WHERE business_id = '$business_id'");
                        $row_like_businesswise = $like_count_businesswise->result();
                        $businesswisecount = $row_like_businesswise['0']->business_wise_like;

                        // code for count business_wise_like ends here 

                        if($res_whole_criteria -> num_rows > 0)
                        {
                                $resultsDoExist = 'true'; // code edited 
                                $response['success'] = "1";
                                $response['message'] = "List found for near by Business Data";
                                $response["data"] = array();
                                $counter = 0;
                                foreach($row_whole_criteria as $row)
                                {
                                        $data = array();
                                        $offerimage = $row->image;
                                        $businessimage = $row->business_image;
                                        $data['Primary Offer Discount'] = $row->discount;
                                        $data['Offer Image'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/dealsnow/public/images/CATEGORIES/"."$offerimage";
                                        $data['Business Type'] = $row->name;
                                        $data['Business Name'] = $row->business_name;
                                        $data['Business Information']=$row->business_desc;
                                        $data['Business Image'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/dealsnow/public/images/business_image/"."$businessimage";
                                        $data['Offer Name'] = $row->title;
                                        $data['Offer Address'] = $row->address;
                                        $data['Phone Number'] = $row->mobile;
                                        $data['Original Price'] = $row->original_price;
                                        $data['business Id'] = $row->business_id;
                                        $data['Expiry Date']= $row->end_date;
                                        $data['Latitude']= $row->latitude;
                                        $data['Longitude']= $row->longitude;
                                        $data['Like Status']= '0';
                                        $data['Favorite Status']= '1';
                                        $data['Like Count']= $businesswisecount;
                                        array_push($response["data"], $data);
                                        $counter++;
                                }
                                echo $output2 = json_encode(array('responsedata' => $response));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                $response = array();
                                $response ["success"] = 0;          
                                $response ["message"] = "Error.";
                                $output2 = json_encode(array('responsedata' => $response));
                                echo $output2;
                        }
    }
```

**EDIT :**

```
 foreach() // main foreach
        {
             $resultsDoExist = 'false';
             if($res -> num_rows > 0)
             {
                        $resultsDoExist = 'true';
                        if($resultsDoExist = 'false')
                        {
                            foreach ($variable as $key) {   // sub foreach 
                                // data 
                            }
                        }
                        if($resultsDoExist == 'false')
                        {   
                            echo "no data found";
                        }                       
             }
        }
```

Comment: Just use some flag `$resultsDoExist` which is initially set to false and changed to true the moment you find _any_ results. Then at the end you can use that flag to decide if any results were found at all and react accordingly.

Comment: @arkascha. Thank you for the reply i have updated my code with your suggestion. but after making it true how can we check at the end  i didn't got it ?

Comment: @arkascha. i tried with if($res_whole_criteria -> num_rows > 0 || $resultsDoExist == 'true') in above code also.

Comment: First, `$$resultsDoExist` is something different than `$resultsDoExist`, but that might be a typo here. Next you need to place your `else` branch _outside_ the `foreach` loop if I understand your question correct, since that is an answer about the _total_ success or not. So _after_ the loop is closed you place a conditional evaluating that flag. If it is true nothing happens, if it is false (no results exist), then no results were sent and you can instead send your error message.

Comment: @arkascha. yeah sorry it was typo. I have edited my question as per your instruction please see that i have followed your insturction properly or not ?

Comment: No you have not. The flag has to be initialized outside the main loop, the evaluation has to be placed outside the main loop too.

Comment: @arkascha. Oh great it's working perfect thank you so much for your precious time please add your answer so i can accept it ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125057/discussion-between-bhavin-and-arkascha).

Comment: Sure, what's up, what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

this code works for if first category is not return any thing then to to else if block other wise not.

```
foreach ($category_id_array as $single_cat_value) {
                    $res_whole_criteria = $this->db->query("SELECT * , ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(  '$latitude' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( longitude ) - RADIANS(  '$longitude' ) ) + SIN( RADIANS(  '$latitude' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, information_business.name AS business_name FROM information_business LEFT JOIN category ON information_business.category_id = category.id LEFT JOIN offers ON offers.category_id = category.id WHERE category.id =  '$single_cat_value' HAVING distance < 10 ORDER BY distance");

                    $row_whole_criteria = $res_whole_criteria->result();
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($row_whole_criteria);
                    $resultsDoExist = 'false';   // code edited 
                    $business_id = $row_whole_criteria['0']->business_id;

                    // code for count business_wise_like starts here 

                    $like_count_businesswise = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT( id ) AS business_wise_like FROM  `business_likes` WHERE business_id = '$business_id'");
                    $row_like_businesswise = $like_count_businesswise->result();
                    $businesswisecount = $row_like_businesswise['0']->business_wise_like;

                    // code for count business_wise_like ends here 

                    if($res_whole_criteria -> num_rows > 0)
                    {
                            $resultsDoExist = 'true'; // code edited 
                            $response['success'] = "1";
                            $response['message'] = "List found for near by Business Data";
                            $response["data"] = array();
                            $counter = 0;
                            foreach($row_whole_criteria as $row)
                            {
                                    $data = array();
                                    $offerimage = $row->image;
                                    $businessimage = $row->business_image;
                                    $data['Primary Offer Discount'] = $row->discount;
                                    $data['Offer Image'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/dealsnow/public/images/CATEGORIES/"."$offerimage";
                                    $data['Business Type'] = $row->name;
                                    $data['Business Name'] = $row->business_name;
                                    $data['Business Information']=$row->business_desc;
                                    $data['Business Image'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]."/dealsnow/public/images/business_image/"."$businessimage";
                                    $data['Offer Name'] = $row->title;
                                    $data['Offer Address'] = $row->address;
                                    $data['Phone Number'] = $row->mobile;
                                    $data['Original Price'] = $row->original_price;
                                    $data['business Id'] = $row->business_id;
                                    $data['Expiry Date']= $row->end_date;
                                    $data['Latitude']= $row->latitude;
                                    $data['Longitude']= $row->longitude;
                                    $data['Like Status']= '0';
                                    $data['Favorite Status']= '1';
                                    $data['Like Count']= $businesswisecount;
                                    array_push($response["data"], $data);
                                    $counter++;
                            }
                            echo $output2 = json_encode(array('responsedata' => $response));
                    }

                    if( $resultsDoExist=='false')
                    {
                            $response = array();
                            $response ["success"] = 0;          
                            $response ["message"] = "Error.";
                            $output2 = json_encode(array('responsedata' => $response));
                            echo $output2;
                    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the reply brother but if second category has some data than also i have show data like if there is a 1,2,3,4,5 categories and if 1,3,5 has no data than it must show 2,4 categories data.